# How to hold screen position when data added in react?

Tags: reactjs, list

I have a list in react that added more rows with interval,
my problem is that when the list grown the screen going up.
I want to hold the position of screen how he was before I added rows to list.

That is my code:

```
 setInterval(() => {
//this row save the position of the screen before the adding row     
setPrevRef({scrollHeight:tabElement.current.scrollHeight,scrollTop:tabElement.current.scrollTop})

                props.setFilteredPT (prev=> [newRow,...prev])

            }, 10000);
```

and

```
 useEffect(()=>{

        tabElement.current.scrollTop =prevRef.scrollTop + (tabElement.current.scrollHeight - prevRef.scrollHeight )

    },[props.filteredPT])
```

After I wrote this code the screen going up to a second and than comeback to the place.

here is how react does it with class component:  https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#reading-dom-properties-before-an-update
but I want do it with function component.
Somebody can help?

Comment: instead of componentDidUpdate use useEffect and use listRef as reference to update inside useEffect.If there are changes in listRef then the useEffect will get triggered

Comment: Can also checkout https://medium.com/@mikolajkocieda/react-hooks-keep-scroll-position-during-change-list-views-cd86463f9629

Answer (score 0):

I had found that my problem cause I used for map key the index, when I have changed it to uniq ID it worked good.